BootstrapActions Failing to create a hdfs directory
I need to create a hdfs folder for my run_job_flow to work. Currently I am using this sh script command sudo -u hdfs hdfs dfs -mkdir -p /apps/hudi/lib but for some reason I am getting this error : mkdir: '/apps/hudi/lib': Input/output error'. If I connect to the cluster using ssh and run the command it works. I also tried without sudo and diferente sudo users.
This is my jobflow:

client.run_job_flow(
    Name="BackupJob",
    ReleaseLabel="emr-6.15.0",
    Instances={
        "InstanceGroups": [my-nodes],
        "Ec2KeyName": ec2_config["KeyName"],
        "EmrManagedMasterSecurityGroup": ec2_config["EmrManagedMasterSecurityGroup"],
        "EmrManagedSlaveSecurityGroup": ec2_config["EmrManagedSlaveSecurityGroup"],
        "Ec2SubnetId": ec2_config["SubnetId"],
        "AdditionalMasterSecurityGroups": ec2_config["AdditionalMasterSecurityGroups"],
        "AdditionalSlaveSecurityGroups": ec2_config["AdditionalSlaveSecurityGroups"],
        "KeepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps": True,
    },
    Applications=[
        {"Name": "Hadoop"},
        {"Name": "Hive"},
        {"Name": "Spark"},
        {"Name": "JupyterEnterpriseGateway"},
        {"Name": "Livy"},
    ],
    Configurations=[
        {
            "Classification": "livy-conf",
            "Properties": {
                "livy.file.local-dir-whitelist": "/usr/lib/hudi",
                "livy.server.session.timeout": "6h",
            },
        },
        {
            "Classification": "hadoop-env",
            "Configurations": [
                {
                    "Classification": "export",
                    "Properties": {"JAVA_HOME": "/usr/lib/jvm/jre-17"},
                }
            ],
            "Properties": {},
        },
        {
            "Classification": "spark",
            "Properties": {"maximizeResourceAllocation": "true"},
        },
        {
            "Classification": "hive-site",
            "Properties": {
                "hive.metastore.client.factory.class": "com.amazonaws.glue.catalog.metastore.AWSGlueDataCatalogHiveClientFactory"
            },
        },
        {
            "Classification": "spark-hive-site",
            "Properties": {
                "hive.metastore.client.factory.class": "com.amazonaws.glue.catalog.metastore.AWSGlueDataCatalogHiveClientFactory"
            },
        },
    ],
    BootstrapActions=[
        {
            "Name": "Set up hudi",
            "ScriptBootstrapAction": {
                "Path": "s3_path_to_my_script"
            },
        },
    ]


It is likely stems from the initialization state of HDFS at the time the bootstrap action runs. HDFS may not yet be fully initialized and ready to accept commands when your script is executed.
Using a delay or moving the directory creation to a custom step after cluster startup should resolve the problem. Debugging the logs will provide further insight.
